# Trying to create a python function that creates an ec2 with aws marketplace software

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to make a function that should launch an ec2 instance that contains aws marketplace software. What commands from the boto3 documents would you guys recommend because I am having trouble searching for one that

1. launches a new ec2
2. utilizes the aws marketplace software product code to launch with the ami
   Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely want to make use of the [`DescribeImages`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html) and [`RunInstances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) actions, which are available methods in the `boto3` API ([`describe_images`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images) and [`run_instances`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)).

The following snippet is a brief example that uses a [product code](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/server/procurement?productId=3b73ef49-208f-47e1-8a6e-4ae768d8a333) from the AWS Marketplace to launch a new EC2 instance using the image ID:

```py
import boto3


def main():
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    # Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Bionic
    product_id = "3b73ef49-208f-47e1-8a6e-4ae768d8a333"
    response = client.describe_images(
        Filters=[{"Name": "name", "Values": [f"*{product_id}*"]}]
    )
    images = response["Images"]
    image = images[0]
    image_id = image["ImageId"]  # ami-02ad37ec9b98d835f
    response = client.run_instances(
        ImageId=image_id,
        InstanceType="t2.micro",
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        SubnetId="<your_subnet_id>",
    )
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This seems like what i was looking for thank you for this. Also would all of the values in red under the main function be able to be variable or must they remain constant? meaning if i run this will it be possible for the command line to receive arguments that may change these values?

Comment: Certainly. By using a module like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), you can process command line arguments and then use the values as parameters to the `describe_images` and `run_instances` methods.

Comment: Sorry again but can you elaborate on the ```if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()``` segment of the code? I am having trouble figuring out what goes there.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) documentation should answer your question. Essentially, `__main__` defines the entry point of the script.